# How do I limit the number of commits shows in git log per page but continue the pagination upon pressing spacebar?

Tags: git

I want to limit the commits shown in one go, right now it's maximum the screen can show. If I use `git diff --oneline -20` it stops after 20, i want to continue after 20.

Comment: Do you want it to redraw when you change pages or just scroll? Meaning show only 20 lines the screen at a time or advance by 20 lines each time?

Comment: continue adding lines, though it'd be useful if there was a line to visually add reference, even some gaping would be useful, but this is optional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the pager in your local or global git config

```
git config --global core.pager "less -20"
```

Comment: If you omit `--global` it will be for the one repo